# Android Custom List View with pictures and sub items search view not working

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview

I have a `searchView` I want to filter the resName, resLoc, resType, but unfortunately it's not working

```
public class caloocan  extends AppCompatActivity {
    String FIREBASE_URL = "https://restaulist1.firebaseio.com";
    Firebase firebaseRef;
    private List<caloocanDB> Restau = new ArrayList<>();
    SearchView searchView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.caloocan);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
       // populateListView();
       // populateRestauList();

        final MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRest);
        //populate restau List
      firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String[] resName = new String[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];
                String[] resLoc = new String[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];
                String[] resType = new String[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];
                int i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    resName[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("resname").getValue().toString();
                    resLoc[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("resloc").getValue().toString();
                    resType[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("foodtype").getValue().toString();
                    Restau.add(new caloocanDB(resName[i], resLoc[i], R.drawable.six, resType[i]));
                    i++;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<caloocanDB> {
        public ArrayList<caloocanDB> tempRestList = new ArrayList<>();
        public MyListAdapter(){
            super(caloocan.this, R.layout.caloocan_list_view, Restau);
            tempRestList = new ArrayList<caloocanDB>(Restau);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View caloocanView = convertView;
            if (caloocanView == null)
                caloocanView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.caloocan_list_view, parent, false);

            caloocanDB restaurant = Restau.get(position);
            //FILL VIEW
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(restaurant.getIconID());
            // RESTAU NAME
            TextView restauName = (TextView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.resnameTxt);
            restauName.setText(restaurant.getResname());
            //RESTAU LOCA
            TextView location = (TextView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.reslocTxt);
            location.setText(restaurant.getResloc());
            //FOOD TYPE
            TextView restype = (TextView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.restypeTxt);
            restype.setText(restaurant.getType());
            return caloocanView;
        }
        public void filter(String text) {
            Restau.clear();

            for (caloocanDB element : tempRestList) {
                if (element.getResname().toLowerCase().startsWith(text) || element.getType().toLowerCase().startsWith(text) || element.getResloc().toLowerCase().startsWith(text)){
                    Restau.add(element);
                }
            }
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I added breakpoint in `adapter.filter();`
and this is the result when i typed something in the searchView [image]

I want to filter the resName, resLoc, resType but nothing filters,
Looking at the picture under adapter > mObjects the 0,1,2,3,4,5 are my listview items with text. I want to Filter it

Comment: can you post your adapter code??

Comment: check the updated @himanshu1496

Comment: and can you tell by which element of your caloocanDB object you want to filter the list??

Comment: @himanshu1496 - all of it , resName, resLoc, resType . i'm creating a flexible search engine

Comment: `adapter.getFilter().filter(text);` where is the filter method code in the question ?

Comment: @Shubhank check the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By which property are you filtering,you can write a method in Adapter according to that,for example your filtering with restaurant name , then write below code

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<caloocanDB> {
        public static ArrayList<coloocanDB> tempRestList = new ArrayList<>();
        public static ArrayList<coloocanDB> restList = new ArrayList<>();
        public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<caloocanDB> objects){
            super(caloocan.this, R.layout.caloocan_list_view, objects);        tempRestList = new ArrayList<>();
            restList = objects;
            tempRestList.addAll(objects);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View caloocanView = convertView;
            if (caloocanView == null)
                caloocanView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.caloocan_list_view, parent, false);

            caloocanDB restaurant = restList.get(position);
            //FILL VIEW
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(restaurant.getIconID());
            // RESTAU NAME
            TextView restauName = (TextView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.resnameTxt);
            restauName.setText(restaurant.getResname());
            //RESTAU LOCA
            TextView location = (TextView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.reslocTxt);
            location.setText(restaurant.getResloc());
            //FOOD TYPE
            TextView restype = (TextView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.restypeTxt);
            restype.setText(restaurant.getType());
            return caloocanView;
        }


     public void filter(String filter) {
      restList.clear();
      if(filter != null && filter.trim().length() > 0){
        for (caloocanDB element : tempRestList){
          if (element.getResname().contains(filter) || element.getType().contains(filter) || element.getResLoc().contains(filter))
             restList.add(element);
          }
      }else{
             restList.addAll(tempRestList);
      } 
      super.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

And in your searchView Listener

```
   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            adapter.filter(text);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And in your Activity

```
firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String[] resName = new String[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];
                String[] resLoc = new String[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];
                String[] resType = new String[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];
                int i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    resName[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("resname").getValue().toString();
                    resLoc[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("resloc").getValue().toString();
                    resType[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("foodtype").getValue().toString();
                    Restau.add(new caloocanDB(resName[i], resLoc[i], R.drawable.six, resType[i]));
                    i++;
                }
        final MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(Restau);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRest);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: i want to search resName, resLoc, resType.

Comment: i'm getting an error when I put `  adapter.filter(text);` it does not read any variable or method . because I inserted the `public void filter` after `public view getView`

Comment: can you post logcat
?

Comment: ops sorry, there are no errors in the program but public void filter is not in used . and when i put `adapter.filter(text);`  the `filter` is not recognized

Comment: check the updated answer it will work,remove override and update the filter method as above,it will work for all filters like resType,resLoc,ResName

Comment: `cannot resolve method filter(java.lang.String)` to the onQueryChange help :(

Comment: do you added filter method to your  Adapter,i've edited your Adapter and added filter method in it,copy that and paste

Comment: done, still error. the searchView is inside the onCreate, and adapter after the onCreate,all in one class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114543/discussion-between-rajan-ks-and-allen-francisco).

Comment: not working dude. everytime i type something in the searchView, the listView will be gone and needed to be refreshed to view it again

Comment: Hey i've edited it,this time it will work no doubt about that,just change the constructor of adapter as per my new update.you're good to go

Comment: still none filters rajan

Comment: And tempRestList size = 0 i debugged it

Comment: and in mObjects, it gets the resName, resLoc, resType but nothing filters

Comment: one last thin. it only searched the first word on the data. how can i search the second word ex. "Burger stop" it only searches the burger. when i type stop. i does not.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Allen you can try something like below, and the search logic inside filter class can be modified based on your search requirements, In the below code search will consider the string as result if it starts with those character sequence.

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<caloocanDB> {
public static ArrayList<coloocanDB> tempRestList = new ArrayList<>();
public MyListAdapter(){
    super(caloocan.this, R.layout.caloocan_list_view, Restau);              tempRestList = Restau;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View caloocanView = convertView;
    if (caloocanView == null)
        caloocanView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.caloocan_list_view, parent, false);

    caloocanDB restaurant = Restau.get(position);
    //FILL VIEW
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(restaurant.getIconID());
    // RESTAU NAME
    TextView restauName = (TextView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.resnameTxt);
    restauName.setText(restaurant.getResname());
    //RESTAU LOCA
    TextView location = (TextView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.reslocTxt);
    location.setText(restaurant.getResloc());
    //FOOD TYPE
    TextView restype = (TextView)caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.restypeTxt);
    restype.setText(restaurant.getType());
    return caloocanView;
}


public void filter(String text) {
Restau.clear();
for (caloocanDB element : tempRestList) {
     if (element.getResname().toLowerCase().startsWith(text) || element.getType().toLowerCase().startsWith(text) || element.getResLoc().toLowerCase().startsWith(text)){
          Restau.add(element);
     }                
}

super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea, but constrain cannot resolved symbol.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to change that variable, please check my updated answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the adapter empty and therefore nothing is filtered.

Change your initialisation to be done after you get data from the Firebase

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRest);
    //populate restau List

//inside the dataobserver
for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
       resName[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("resname").getValue().toString();
       resLoc[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("resloc").getValue().toString();
       resType[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("foodtype").getValue().toString();
       Restau.add(new caloocanDB(resName[i], resLoc[i], R.drawable.six, resType[i]));
       i++;
}
MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(Restau);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```